# actionscript 3 key release stop sound

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, keypress

hi im really new to actionscript and ive have a problem with playing sound. I want my sound to stop playing when i release the up key. ive manged to get the sound to play on a key press.

Heres my code...

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

var mySound:Sound = new carstart();

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, playSound);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stopSound);

function playSound(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 38) {
        mySound.play();
    }
}

function stopSound(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 38) {
     mySound.stop();
    }
}
```

i get this error

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 29  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method stop through a reference with static type flash.media:Sound.
```

if you can think of anything it would be a great help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

var mySound:Sound = new carstart();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

myChannel = mySound.play();

function playSound(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 38) {
        mySound.play();
    }
}

function stopSound(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 38) {
     myChannel.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `Sound` object into a `SoundChannel`...
Follow [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2563.htm) example , and you will be set in no time!